# OneHotEncoder not working for strings inputs, ERROR: ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am working on building a pipeline with a OHE step, whenever I try to fit my pipeline (or when my CV tries to fit) I get the error `ValueError: could not convert string to float`

I am using sklearn version 1.2.0 so my OneHotEncoder should be able to handle strings, I have seen some potentially outdated questions/answers that suggest labelEncoder/labelBinarizer but I don't think that is the best answer for my problem because those aren't meant to be used on X data in a pipeline.

Here is the code I am using to build my pipeline

```
X_data = data.drop(y_cols,axis=1)
categorical_mask = (X_data.dtypes=='object')
categorical_columns = X_data.columns[categorical_mask].tolist()

# ohe_unique_list = [X_data[c].unique().tolist() for c in categorical_columns]
ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore',sparse_output=False)
imp = SimpleImputer(strategy='constant',fill_value='NA')
preprocess = ColumnTransformer([
    ('imputer',imp, categorical_columns),
    ('ohe',ohe, categorical_columns)],
    remainder='passthrough'
)

selector = RFECV(estimator=XGBClassifier())

estimator = XGBClassifier()
steps = [
    ('preprocess',preprocess),
    ('selector',selector),
    ('clf', estimator)
]

pl = Pipeline(steps)
```

I have tried specifying the unique categories, removing the imputer, and also processing the strings to remove any leading/trailing whitespace. What can I do to prevent this error so I can fit the pipeline? In the meantime I am just using the pandas get_dummies function for my categorical features (which works fine), but ultimately I want to get the pipeline functional so I can use it with new features.